# plotly graph edge label

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I want to add label to Graph in `plotly`. I wrote a program like this but it doesn't work

```
edge_trace = Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    line=Line(width=3, color='rgba(136, 136, 136, .8)', text=[]),
    hoverinfo='none',
    text='',
    mode='lines')

for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = pos[edge[0]]
    x1, y1 = pos[edge[1]]
    edge_trace['x'] += [x0, x1, None]
    edge_trace['y'] += [y0, y1, None]
    edge_trace['line']['text'].append('label')
```

I got the following error:

```
    raise exceptions.PlotlyDictKeyError(self, path)
    plotly.exceptions.PlotlyDictKeyError: 'line' is not allowed in 'line'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add labels to the edges you need to set the mode to `'lines+text'` then set the `text` attribute to be a list of the labels. See the 3d example below:

```
trace3 = go.Scatter3d(x=Xe2, y=Ye2, z=Ze2,
                         mode='lines+text',
                         line=dict(color='rgb(0,125,0)', width=4),
                         hoverinfo='none',
                         text=link_labels,
                         textposition='bottom right',
                         textfont=dict(
                             size=20
                         ),
                     )
```

Where `link_labels` is a list of length equal to that of `Xe2`, `Ye2`, and `Ze2`.

Comment: This solution -for adding labels to edges- doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `text` attribute is a not a [`line`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-line) attribute.

Something like:

```
edge_trace = Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    line=Line(width=3, color='rgba(136, 136, 136, .8)'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    text=[],
    mode='lines')

for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = pos[edge[0]]
    x1, y1 = pos[edge[1]]
    edge_trace['x'] += [x0, x1, None]
    edge_trace['y'] += [y0, y1, None]
    edge_trace['text'].append('label')
```

should work.

Comment: Can you help me out a little more? Does it output an error? Does it not show the text?

Comment: If anyone ends up in this page because they're looking for a way to add a hover text on edges, this feature is not possible in plotly. You can find an alternative approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037897/line-hover-text-in-plotly)