# Plotly (Dash) Hover over line between two points and get value - python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Plotting the below using a pandas dataframe and plotly:

[image: plotly scatter graph]

Using ploty express:

```
    fig= px.line(
             df.sort_values(by='allocation'),
             x='allocation',
             y='cost')

    fig.data[0].update(mode='markers+lines',
             line = dict(shape = 'linear', color = 'rgb(10, 12, 240)', dash = 'dash'),
             connectgaps = True,)
```

When I hover over the markers I get the expected pop-up with the x and y values named correctly. Is there any way to get the same when hovering over the *line* that is drawn by `connectgaps=True`? So hovering on the line between two points would give me the x and y values of that point of the created line?

I'm hoping to avoid having to create a formula and add a line to the figure for each separate segment (and working out the best way to do that!).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line hover text in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037897/line-hover-text-in-plotly)

Comment: Thanks - it certainly leads to the answer: https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-hover-event-not-getting-triggered-for-al-data-points/387 . Looks like the functionality doesn't exist and I'll need to generate points to fill in between the existing ones in order for trigger to hover.

Comment: My comment is an automatically generated comment when you flag a question as duplicate. I got to that question with one google search. Please do your research before submitting a question :)